# Why is this snippet compilable in C?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, declaration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C arrays why is this true? a[5] == 5[a]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/in-c-arrays-why-is-this-true-a5-5a)

3["zdvnngfgnfg"];

Comment: Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/in-c-arrays-why-is-this-true-a5-5a/381549#381549 as well

Answer (score 9):

It's equivalent to

```
"zdvnngfgnfg"[3];
```

which is legal and means "take the address of that literal and add `3*sizeof(char)` to it". Will have no effect anyway.

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/in-c-arrays-why-is-this-true-a5-5a) very similar question.

Comment: Doesn't the meaning also include "and then fetch the value at that address"?

Comment: I suppose no, since the statement is neither on the left nor on the right side of the assignment.

Comment: Since the snippet is a full expression, it does in fact mean "and then fetch the value". But because doing so has no defined side-effects, and the result is discarded, the compiler is allowed to omit it. In fact the compiler will probably omit the pointer addition as well - all it will do is make sure the statement is legal, realise it does nothing, and elide it. Certainly that's what gcc does, even with no optimisation.

Comment: In C, an expression that appears as an expression statement is converted to an rvalue: The value therein is accessed. "Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the unary & operator, the ++ operator, the -- operator, or the left operand of the . operator or an assignment operator, an lvalue that does not have array type is converted to the value stored in the designated object". The behavior is different from C++, in which no value is fetched if the read wasn't requested. But surely, you won't notice the difference since the array isn't volatile :)

Comment: Indexing a constant string makes for especially nice-looking code when used to convert to a hexadecimal digit: char digit = "0123456789ABCDEF"[i];

Answer (score 6):

arr[i] is parsed as *(arr+i) which can be written as *(i+arr) and hence i[arr]
Now "strngjwdgd" is a pointer to a constant character array stored at read only location.
so it works!!

Answer (score 2):

The string literal(`array`) decays to a pointer of type `char*`. Then you take the fourth element:

```
3["zdvnngfgnfg"] == "zdvnngfgnfg"[3]
```

Why you can write the subscript infront of the array is another question:

[In C arrays why is this true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/in-c-arrays-why-is-this-true-a5-5a)